# Variable user-defined parameter list in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a simple way to create a user multi-parameter receiving function,

Here's some pseudo code

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
   int m_num;
};

void function(A* a, ...)
{
    /* Pseudo-Code here */
    for each parameter do 
        print a->m_num
    end
}

int main()
{
   A *a = new A();
   A *b = new A();
   A *c = new A();

   a->m_num = 1;
   b->m_num = 10;
   c->m_num = 100;

   function(a,b,c);

   // delete everything

   return 0;
}
```

I can't really use boost here, so if it's possible with standard C++ ( STL Allowed ), it would be great.

EDIT: The function parameters are heterogeneous

Comment: Can you use C++0x? It's not possible with C++98 if you don't provide a senitel value or the number of parameters.

Comment: If the parameters are all of the same type, why can you not pass in an `std::array<>` or `std::vector<>`? What you're asking for only seems useful for heterogeneous types.

Comment: Can you not use a `std::map`? Make the value a union (URGH) or alternatively a simple structure with a type hint and a string field, use the hint to convert the string to the type (URGH).

Comment: @KennyTM I can't use 0x , but it would be interesting to see an answer using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old school plain C variadic arguments:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdarg.h>

struct A {
    A () : m_num (0) {}
    A (int v) : m_num (v) {}
    int m_num;
};

void function (A *a, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    A *p = a;
    va_start (ap, a);
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%d\n", p->m_num);
        p = va_arg (ap, A*);
    }
    va_end (ap);
}

int main()
{
    A a (1), b (10), c (100);
    function (&a, &b, &c, NULL);
}
```

Another solution if arguments are of the same type (which is your case):

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A {
    A () : m_num (0) {}
    A (int v) : m_num (v) {}
    int m_num;
};

void function (A *p, A *endp)
{
    while (p != endp)
    {
        printf ("%d\n", p->m_num);
        ++p;
    }
}

int main()
{
    A a[3];
    a[0].m_num = 1;
    a[1].m_num = 10;
    a[2].m_num = 100;
    function (a, a + sizeof (a) / sizeof(a[0]));
}
```

Or even more C++-style, with iterators:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

struct A {
    A () : m_num (0) {}
    A (int v) : m_num (v) {}
    int m_num;
};

template <typename T>
void function (T p, T endp)
{
    while (p != endp)
    {
        printf ("%d\n", p->m_num);
        ++p;
    }
}

int main()
{
    A a[3];
    a[0].m_num = 1;
    a[1].m_num = 10;
    a[2].m_num = 100;
    function (a, a + sizeof (a) / sizeof(a[0]));

    std::vector<A> av (3);
    av[0].m_num = 1;
    av[1].m_num = 10;
    av[2].m_num = 100;
    function (av.begin (), av.end ());

    std::list<A> al;
    al.push_back (A (1));
    al.push_back (A (10));
    al.push_back (A (100));
    function (al.begin (), al.end ());
}
```

Comment: This solution seems good, I've read that va_list is platform dependent though, but you are avoiding the construction of an std::vector. What would be the benefit of this solution over creating an std::vector ?

Comment: The implementation of `va_list` varies across platforms, but the code is portable.  The benefit of this over creating a vector is, well, you don't have to create a vector, so there is less unnecessary code.  The downside of this is that if you forget to put the NULL at the end of your calls to this function, bad things happen.  It's a stylistic choice that depends on how you are going to use it.

Comment: Lol beat me to it... It's called Variable Argument Lists http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaawxy2f.aspx

Comment: Mr. Gando: I don't think that std::vector will buy me anything here. And using vector doesn't seem straightforward for me as well. Not to mention that it calls malloc.... Doing pointer arithmetic and/or iterators in this case is the way to go as all arguments are of the same type. Usually, vararg is used for different types of arguments, as in printf-like functions. Vector there won't help, only variadic templates from C++0x can solve that better.

Comment: @Vlad, yeah I'm aware of what std::vector does behind your back :), thanks for the answer. Accepted.

Comment: Mr.Gando: I've added one more solution, beware it won't work for non continuous memory where you cannot apply pointer-arithmetics. Unless these are higher-level iterators. But works beautifully for STL containers and plain arrays. I.e. in your original examples A* instances might not be layed out continuously, so it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is to put your parameters into a `std::vector`. If they're non-homogeneous you can use a vector of `boost::any` or `boost::variant`.

Alternately design your interface like streams and use an insertion like operator/function that operators on one parameter at a time.

It would look something like this, alternately using a friend free-function.

```
struct A
{
   int m_num;
};

struct printer
{
function& operator<<(A* a)
{
    /* Pseudo-Code here */
    print a->m_num

    return *this;
}
};

int main()
{
   A *a = new A();
   A *b = new A();
   A *c = new A();

   a->m_num = 1;
   b->m_num = 10;
   c->m_num = 100;

   printer function;
   function << a << b << c;

   // delete everything

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would really love to avoid constructing an std::vector, the parameters are homogeneous. Could you provide an example ?

Answer (score 0):

If every parameter going into function is an A, I'd do it with an array of A's, as in:

```
int main() {
  A *abc[3];

  for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    abc[i]=new A();

  abc[0]->m_num=1;
  abc[1]->m_num=10;
  abc[2]->m_num=100;

  function(abc,3);
}

void function(A *vals[],int count) {
  for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
    print vals[i]->m_num;
}
```

Comment: I would use a `std::vector`, because it's even simpler (e.g. doesn't require a `count` parameter).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a compiler recent enough to ship with `std::tuple<>` or `std::tr1::tuple<>`, you can do the following:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int m_num;
};

template<typename T>
class function_impl
{
    template<std::size_t N>
    static void impl(T const& tup)
    {
        std::cout << std::get<N>(tup)->m_num << '\n';
    }

    template<std::size_t N>
    struct recurse_helper
    {
        static void invoke(T const& tup)
        {
            function_impl<T>::template impl<N>(tup);
            recurse_helper<N + 1u>::invoke(tup);
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct recurse_helper<std::tuple_size<T>::value>
    {
        static void invoke(T const&) { }
    };

public:
    static void invoke(T const& tup)
    {
        recurse_helper<0u>::invoke(tup);
    }
};

template<typename T>
void function(T const& tup)
{
    function_impl<T>::invoke(tup);
}

int main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    a->m_num = 1;

    A* b = new A();
    b->m_num = 10;

    A* c = new A();
    c->m_num = 100;

    function(std::tie(a, b, c));

    delete c;
    delete b;
    delete a;
}
```

Note that `function` actually takes a singular argument, a `tuple<>`, rather than multiple arguments. But, unlike any `varargs`-based solution, this is completely type-safe.

Also note that the implementation here would be **much** simpler if you could use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/index.html)...

Comment: OMG. I love C++, but this is an overkill. Head-shot!

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko : This is essentially just a reimplementation of `boost::fusion::for_each`; if the OP wanted to use boost, the code would be just as short as a `std::vector<>` + `std::for_each` based solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement.

In C++0x, you could use variadic-template to implement your function *recursively*:

```
// Just to make the compiler happy.
template <typename T>
void function(T a) = delete;

// Base case
template <>
void function(A* a) {
    printf("%d\n", a->m_num);
}

// Recursion
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void function(T a, Args... args) {
    function(a);
    function(args...);
}
```

But this will generate *N* functions if it accepts *N* parameters. Alternatively, you could use an `initializer_list`:

```
void function(std::initializer_list<A*> args) {
    for (auto cit = args.begin(); cit != args.end(); ++ cit)
        printf("%d\n", (*cit)->m_num);
}
```

but you need to call `function` as

```
function({a,b,c});
//       ^     ^
```